# Ordering boxplots from different dataframes manually on the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

How can I manually order the boxplots, for instance, switching boxplot a with c, in the following example?

```
library(ggplot2)
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 13, 15,
                      11, 11, 12, 14, 15, 19, 22, 24,
                      19, 23, 23, 23, 24, 26, 29, 33))

df2 <- data.frame(b=c(5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 13, 15,
                      11, 18, 12, 14, 50, 19, 22, 24,
                      19, 23, 23, 23, 24, 28, 31, 33))


df3 <- data.frame(c=c(5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 13, 15,
                      11, 11, 12, 14, 30, 19, 22, 24,
                      19, 23, 23, 23, 24, 26, 29, 33))


ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data = df1, aes(x = 'a', y=a)) +
  geom_boxplot(data = df2, aes(x = 'b', y=b)) + 
  geom_boxplot(data = df3, aes(x = 'c', y=c))
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `... +  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("c", "b", "a"))` to manually reorder the boxplots - that said, it typically makes more sense to have your data in a single data frame as given in the answer below.

Comment: That works perfectly. Regarding Peter's answer, it is also valid but the data I am working with is a bit complicated so I prefer to use your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You might be better of combining the dataframes and use longer format so your data is 'tidy' and you only have to deal with one dataframe. Then you can manage the order by factors.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(forcats)

  bind_cols(df1, df2, df3) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fct_rev(name), value))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>